# Swift 3: How to give option to choose the phone number to call

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift3

I have a database where the phone numbers are saved (either Landline or Mobile or both). Depending on the record fetch, if the user wants to call the number and the record has both the numbers, mobile and landline, how to give the user an option to choose the number.

```
 @IBAction func makeCall(_ sender: Any) {
    print ("------Phone Number-----")
    print(landline)
    print(phoneNumber)

    let phone = "tel://";
    let lline = landline
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:phone+phoneNumber)!
    let url2:NSURL = NSURL(string: phone+landline)!
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url2 as URL)
}
```

Using the above code, it dials both the numbers but want to give the user to choose either one of it.

Comment: Is there any point against using an UIAlertController for giving the user the choice which number to call?

Comment: @weissja19 no there is no point. How can we use the ALertController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As and add on for weissja19 answer, you should add a canopenurl check before calling the openurl call itself. Also neater if the user does not see an action he cannot perform. I'd recommend you to use a code like this.

```
@IBAction func makeCall(_ sender: Any) {
    print ("------Phone Number-----")
    print(landline)
    print(phoneNumber)

    let phone = "tel://";
    let lline = landline
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:phone+phoneNumber)!
    let url2:NSURL = NSURL(string: phone+landline)!

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: 'Choose a number to call', message: 'Please choose which number you want to call', preferredStyle: .alert)
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenUrl(url as URL) {
        let firstNumberAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Number 1", style: .default, handler: { _ in
             UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
        })
        alert.addAction(firstNumberAction)
    }

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenUrl(url2 as URL) {
        let secondNumberAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Number 2", style: .default, handler: { _ in
             UIApplication.shared.openURL(url2 as URL)
        })
        alert.addAction(secondNumberAction)
    }    
    if alert.actions.count == 0 {
        alert.title = "No numbers to call"
        alert.message = ""
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
    } else {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
    }
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: In swift 3 use native `URL` instead of `NSURL`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a UIAlertController for giving the user the choice:

```
@IBAction func makeCall(_ sender: Any) {
  print ("------Phone Number-----")
  print(landline)
  print(phoneNumber)

  let phone = "tel://";
  let lline = landline
  let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:phone+phoneNumber)!
  let url2:NSURL = NSURL(string: phone+landline)!

  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose a number to call", message: "Please choose which number you want to call", preferredStyle: .alert)

  let firstNumberAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Number 1", style: .default) { (action) in
     UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
  }

  let secondNumberAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Number 2", style: .default) { (action) in
     UIApplication.shared.openURL(url2 as URL)
  }    

  alert.addAction(firstNumberAction)
  alert.addAction(secondNumberAction)
  self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

You could of course also add a cancel action if you like.

Comment: Thanks. But having some errors at **{ _in
     UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)**    and  at **{ _in
     UIApplication.shared.openURL(url2 as URL)**

Comment: says, cannot convert value of type '() -> ()'  to expected argument type '((UIAlertAction)-> Void)?'

Comment: Hi, still the same error message :(.  Same error message at the same lines

Comment: Sorry. Now it should be working. This time I tested it in xcode myself :D

Answer (score 0):

Both the codes are working. The following is the working code

```
 @IBAction func makeCall(_ sender: Any) {
    print ("------Phone Number-----")
    print(landline)
    print(phoneNumber)

    let phone = "tel://";
    let prefix = "03"
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:phone+phoneNumber)!
    let url2:NSURL = NSURL(string: phone+prefix+landline)!

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose a number to call", message: "Please choose which number you want to call", preferredStyle: .alert)
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {
        let firstNumberAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Mobile: " + phoneNumber, style: .default) { (action) in
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
        }
        alert.addAction(firstNumberAction)
    }


    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url2 as URL) {
        let secondNumberAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Landline: " + prefix+landline , style: .default) { (action) in
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url2 as URL)
        }
        alert.addAction(secondNumberAction)
    }
    if alert.actions.count == 0 {
        alert.title = "No numbers to call"
        alert.message = ""
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
    } else {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
    }
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

thanks a alot  to weissja19 and Ben Ong

Comment: `if let url = URL(string:phone+phoneNumber), url2 = URL(string: phone+prefix+landline)  { UIApplication.shared.open(url) }`